# How do I take off body armor?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I've tried holding the back button, turning off body armor and all that, and there's no option in my house to take it off. I have no physical body armor for protection and it is really hard to see my crew emblem this way.

Comment: Try doing the same in a vehicle.

Comment: You should add a tag or specify which platform you are playing on; this might attract more people and make it easier to find an answer

Comment: Also; i don't play gta5 online, but is this the same question? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/205458/how-do-i-remove-armor-vest?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It's in your quick menu.

Hold select (on PS3) for a second -> inventory -> armor

http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Interaction_Menu

Answer (score 1):

For Xbox hold back button and in accessories along with parachutes you can auto show/hide body armor it should take effect right away but if not try going through a loading screen to reboot your character.