# How do I remove Armor Vest?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, ps4

I've seen the other posts and here and elsewhere, I've checked the youtubes, and every answer seems to be for the last gen consoles.
*But how do I remove the Armor Vest from my character in GTA 5 for the PS4?*

I know it's only cosmetic but it's bothering me.

On the PS4 there is no "options" button, I don't see the "inventory", and the menu is different than before.

And is there a way to alter your appearance once you're in game after you've transferred the character from the old system?

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding down the touch pad will open the interactions menu. Once there go to inventory > Body Armor > None

Comment: Hey thanks so much, worked! Not sure why I couldn't figure it out on my own. I must not have been holding the button down long enough because I'd tried that and it kept switching views but never brought up a menu.